# Filter function for Google Sheets - dynamic cell reference

Tags: google-sheets, filter, filtering

this is driving me crazy!

I need to make a FILTER function in GS dynamic to return headers and row data from a table, but ignoring any blank columns. In the table, people will have different columns with data in.

I can build the FILTER expression, but can't make it dynamic. It looks like FILTER needs absolute cells, and won't accept references from other cells (see attached sheet). Please help my sanity! Many thanx

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1pI9UT_LudmVxo9LeUfIi-03gQ939hlsOMke4hQFUVRQ/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In cell `B3`, change your formula

**From:**

```
=FILTER({$7:$7;10:10},NOT(ISBLANK(10:10)))
```

**To:**

```
=FILTER({A7:J7;INDIRECT(C15)},NOT(ISBLANK(INDIRECT(C15))))
```

and in cell `C15`, change your formula

**From:**

```
=MATCH(B15,A8:A13,0)+7 &":"& MATCH(B15,A8:A13,0)+7
```

**To:**

```
="A"&MATCH(B15,A8:A13,0)+7 &":J"& MATCH(B15,A8:A13,0)+7
```

**Output:**

[image]

[image]

### Reference:

- [INDIRECT()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093377?hl=en)

Comment: That's tremendous, thanks. I was trying OFFSET and other things to try and fool GS into thinking an array reference, but that didn't work. I knew there'd be something simple I was missing.
This works without the A and J as well which is neater for my OCD. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you could use query function

```
=QUERY({A7:J13},"SELECT * WHERE Col1='"&B15&"'",1)
```

check `Copy of Sheet1` sheet

Comment: thanks for this. I considered this kind of thing, but I need it to return *only* the columns that are filled with data, along with the headers so I know what the data refers to. The actual sheet I'm struggling  with contains over 50 columns.
This Query only returns all the columns.

Comment: you can add select Col1 instrad of * that way you get only one column